# Clean Swift / VIPER protocol conformance

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently working on a Clean Swift (similar to VIPER) implementation. For each module I have a Presenter and a Displayer (which is a ViewControler in the end) all of it based on protocols.

Those are my generic Displayer and Presenter protocols:

```
// Generic Displayer
protocol BaseDisplayLogic: class {
    func displayError(message: String)
    func displayApiError(error: ApiError)
}

extension BaseDisplayLogic where Self: UIViewController {
    func displayApiError(error: ApiError) {
        if let errorDescription = error.errorDescription {
            self.warningAlert(errorDescription)
        }
    }

    func displayError(message: String) {

    }
}

// Generic Presenter
protocol BasePresentationLogic: class  {

    var viewController: BaseDisplayLogic? { get }


    func presentError(message: String)
    func presentApiError(error: ApiError)

}

extension BasePresentationLogic {


    func presentError(message: String) {

    }

    func presentApiError(error: ApiError) {

    }
}
```

And here it is the implementation of a module I would need:

```
// A displayer
protocol RestorePasswordDisplayLogic: BaseDisplayLogic {
    func displayPasswordRestore(ok: Bool)
}

class RestorePasswordViewController: UIViewController {
}


// A presenter
protocol RestorePasswordPresentationLogic: BasePresentationLogic {
    func presentPasswordRestore(ok: Bool)
}

class RestorePasswordPresenter: RestorePasswordPresentationLogic {
    weak var viewController: RestorePasswordDisplayLogic?


    func presentPasswordRestore(ok: Bool) {
        self.viewController?.displayPasswordRestore(ok: ok)
    }

}
```

The problem is that I am getting an error in the Presenter implementation (RestorePasswordPresenter in this case) because it is not conforming to the BasePresentationLogic protocol.
If I remove the

```
var viewController: BaseDisplayLogic? { get }
```

it works perfectly, but I need the viewController var to be visible from the BasePresentationLogic extension so I can make a default implementation of the presentError and presentApiError methods.

Any idea on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct problem is that you're not conforming to the protocol as required. You required a `viewController` of type `BaseDisplayLogic?`. So you need to create that, and store your more specific version in a backing variable:

```
weak var restorePasswordViewController: RestorePasswordDisplayLogic?
var viewController: BaseDisplayLogic? { restorePasswordViewController }
```

(Personally, and only as an opinion, I think this is wildly overusing protocols, and likely to be a source of many headaches, especially if you ever try to make these pieces generic and start needing type-erasers. If you've been successful with it, more power to you, but maintaining all these parallel class/protocol hierarchies seems a bad idea to me. It's reinventing class inheritance with protocols, which isn't what protocols are for, and they're not very good at it.)

Comment: I partially agree about the protocols overuse. I started with the Clean Swift template and 'kind of' inherited all this stuff but continuously trying to improve it so... any recommendation will be appreciated :)

Comment: If you want the short version of my recommendations on protocols/generics, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvSoXVxN7Aw If you want to see a nice discussion of architecture that avoids adding layers of complexity, see Dave DeLong's "A Better MVC" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWVzCd5FYbs

Comment: (I actually quite like Presenters as a concept. But I think a lot of these "architecture patterns" bury that great idea in too many layers of added boilerplate that isn't helping and makes later refactoring much harder if you find that basic assumptions were wrong.)